# Unable to update the appointment

Tags: php

That is my update php code. Is that any incorrect in my code. Because it always show

> {"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}

```
<?php

 include 'connection.php';

 $response = array();   
 if (isset($_POST['appointmentID']) &&
 isset($_POST['visitName']) && isset($_POST['description']) &&
 isset($_POST['appointmentTime']) && isset($_POST['appointmentDate'])) 
 {

     $appointmentID = $_POST['appointmentID'];
     $visitName = $_POST['visitName'];
     $Description = $_POST['Description'];
     $appointmentTime = $_POST['appointmentTime'];
     $appointmentDate = $_POST['appointmentDate'];

     $conn = new mysqli($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost, $database_localhost);

     $sql ="UPDATE APPOINMENT SET visitName = '$visitName', Description =     '$Description', appointmentTime = '$appointmentTime', appointmentDate = '$appointmentDate' WHERE appointmentID =
 '$appointmentID'";
      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
      {

         $response["success"] = 1;
         $response["message"] = "Feedback successfully submitted!"; 
         // echoing JSON response
         echo json_encode($response);   
      }  
      else 
      {
         $response["success"] = 0;
         $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

         echo json_encode($response);
      } 
 } else  {
     $response["success"] = 0;
     $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

     echo json_encode($response); 
 }

?>
```

Comment: So some field isn't populated. May be you didn't post it with the form..

Comment: Not to mention that this is not how `mysqli_*` should be used..

Comment: sql injection nightmare... you should be escaping those post vars. Can you provide the form you're posting here?